# Extract ALL child div's classes data with iMacros to Excel

Tags: html, web-scraping, extract, imacros

Scenario :** DIV with multiple child. I wished to extract **all the child data** with iMacros into Excel. All my required data is contained in child  **<tr class="odd", <tr class="even", <tr class="odd"**, and so on...

Each class="odd" or class="even" consist of 1 line of data to be extracted. However, class="odd" consist of unique individual column data eg. "rightcelltd 1cell".

Here is the html body part:

```html
<div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="position: relative; overflow: auto; max-height: 310px; height: 310px; width: 100%;">

  <table id="opt_montage_table" class="montage_table dataTable" style="width: 100%;">

    
<tbody>
      <tr class="odd">
          <td class="rightcelltd 1cell">
          <td class="rightcelltd 2cell">
          <td class="rightcelltd 3cell">
      <tr class="even">
          <td class="rightcelltd 1cell">
          <td class="rightcelltd 2cell">
          <td class="rightcelltd 3cell">
      <tr class="odd">
          <td class="rightcelltd 1cell">
          <td class="rightcelltd 2cell">
          <td class="rightcelltd 3cell">
      <tr class="even">
      <tr class="odd">
      <tr class="even">
      <tr class="odd">
      <tr class="even">
```

[image]

I've tried the followings:

1. TAG POS=5 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"dataTables_scrollBody" EXTRACT=TXT
2. TAG POS=5 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=CLASS:"montage_table dataTable" EXTRACT=TXT
3. TAG POS=5 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=CLASS:"opt_montage_table" EXTRACT=TXT
4. TAG POS=5 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=CLASS:"montage_table dataTable" EXTRACT=TXT
5. TAG POS=5 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"montage_table dataTable" EXTRACT=TXT

Unfortunately, they don't work and result in a #enaf#.

Hope some Guru's able to provide some advise or solution to the above. Thanking you in advance for your kindness and time.

Comment: Mini-Rmk, you should place the Screenshot at the Bottom of your Post, many (High-Rep) Users don't like Code and Source Code posted as Image (even if I find it OK in "this Case" because of the "Quantity"), and "introduce" your Screenshot with some mini-Intro/Explanation, or that might get you some Downvote(s)...

Answer (score 1):

Some Tech Info is missing from your Question as you didn't read the [imacros](/questions/tagged/imacros) Tag [Wiki](/imacros/info), but OK..., I can still answer it...

EDIT/Update (Temp): (2022-08-28/29)
Status: Waiting for @OP to create the Parallel Thread (on the iMacros Forum).
<sub>My Answer was "supposed" to be some "easy"/straightforward Solution to @OP's Qt (Question), but apparently not (see the Comments), Thread is now going into some "Debug/Troubleshooting"-Mode, not very suitable for 'SO' as I can't really post "mini-Scripts" to try/test in Comments, => we'll be doing the Troubleshooting part on the iMacros Forum ('[Data-Extraction](https://forum.imacros.net/viewforum.php?f=7)' Sub-Forum, => the 1st/last Thread there I reckon, with the same Thread Title.)</sub>

<sub>[Mod and "Tech Guru" on that Forum, so I have more "Power(s)" about the Content, (and Data-Extraction is my "Specialty", oops..!), and I'll "later" update my Answer (here) with the "final" (working) Solution... (Might take a few days though, depending on if I can do "the Testing" myself, or if only @OP can do it, because Site behind L&P etc...)]</sub>

---

> DIV with multiple child [elements]. I wished to extract all the child data...

=> "*DIV*" + "*multiple child [elements]*" + "*child data*" are a bit *irrelevant*... Rather *important* is that all the Data you want to extract is structured/displayed in a Table (`TABLE`), containing Rows (`TR`s), no Header, and each Row contains 3 Cells (`TD`s).

The number of Rows is probably dynamic, and as you actually want to extract all the Rows/all the Cells, the "easiest" Implementation would be to extract the whole Data in just one `EXTRACT`, => at the `TABLE` Level, like in:

```scala
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=CLASS:"montage_table dataTable" EXTRACT=TXT
```

... which is actually very close to the `TAG POS=5 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=CLASS:"montage_table dataTable" EXTRACT=TXT` that you had tried... (Attempts '2' + '4'.)

---

Also good would be to extract the same `TABLE` using its `ID` (instead of `CLASS`):

```scala
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=ID:"opt_montage_table" EXTRACT=TXT
```

... which is possibly what you tried in Attempt '3'...

I "suppose" both the `CLASS` and the `ID` for that Table will be unique on the Page, => `POS=1`, you might need to "adjust" to `POS=2` etc..., if there are several Tables with the same 'Attributes' on the same Page...

(Not tested, I would need the URL of the Page, your Code Snippet is not runable... (Probably misses some `HTML` + `BODY` Elements, if pure HTML Snippets "work", I don't know, I've never used Snippets for the [imacros](/questions/tagged/imacros) Tag...) ... Oh...!, maybe it "works" actually, but all `HTML` Elements don't contain any (visible/extractable) (`TXT`) Data at all, ah-ah...!, => the Snippet Area appears all Blank, tja...! But nope, won't work, all closing HTML Tags are missing also...)

Comment: Hi chivracq, my deep appreciation for your comment and guidance above. 

Your analysis is correct as the number of Rows is dynamic refreshed every 15mins.

Suggestion of TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=ID:"opt_montage_table" EXTRACT=TXT adjusted to POS=1 to 10 has been tested by myself earlier but still no luck. The reason of using POS=5 was because i'm able to extract specific individual Cell data by using POS=5.

Comment: The URL with viewable data is for paid subscription user, therefore i'm afraid you'll not be able to study the Code Snippets from the URL itself. If you really need them, kindly let me know in return.

Meanwhile, i'm attaching herewith the more detail Code Snipplets in JPG format and hope it'll provide you with a clearer view.

Once again, thanks for your precious time to help. Have a great weekend ahead.

Comment: Hum, OK..., 17 Cells per Row I see, instead of "only" 3 like I thought, but `TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=ID:opt_montage_table EXTRACT=TXT` should work (Double Quotes not needed actually), or `TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=CLASS:montage_table<SP>dataTable EXTRACT=TXT`, or even `TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=CLASS:montage_table*dataTable EXTRACT=TXT`. // You don't have any other `EXTRACT`s "before" by any chance...?, => a `SET !EXTRACT NULL` would be needed, + need to `SAVEAS` to the '.csv' directly when extracting at the `TABLE` Level, or the whole Table will be seen as "one" Cell by 'Excel'.

Comment: Good day chivracq, here are the results based on your kind suggestion:-

1. TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=ID:opt_montage_table EXTRACT=TXT
2. TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=CLASS:montage_table*dataTable EXTRACT=TXT

the above resulted EANF.

However, TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=CLASS:montage_table<SP>dataTable EXTRACT=TXT able to extract the header (description) of the cell.

Comment: FYI, by using iMacros Recorder TAG mode Selector by pointing at the required cell here are the results:-

TAG SELECTOR="#opt_montage_table>TBODY>TR:nth-of-type(13)>TD:nth-of-type(2)"
TAG SELECTOR="#opt_montage_table>TBODY>TR:nth-of-type(5)>TD:nth-of-type(4)>A"
TAG SELECTOR="#opt_montage_table>TBODY>TR:nth-of-type(7)>TD:nth-of-type(4)>A"

Question : is there anyway to further point to TBODY or TBODY>TR for more accurate cell extraction?

Comment: FYI, SET !EXTRACT NULL & SAVEAS was used as per your earlier advise.

Comment: Yeah, but hum, I would have 1-2-3 Sugg(s)/"Things_to_try" for each of your Replies/Results, this Thread is turning into a Debug/Troubleshooting Thread, and this is not really doable on this Site with Comments where you can't really post (mini-)Scripts in Comments, this Site is more about a "straight" Q/A, and I expected my Answer to be that "straight Solution" to your Question. Then hum, I would suggest opening a parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum ([Data-Extraction Sub-Forum](https://forum.imacros.net/viewforum.php?f=7)) (Mod & "Tech Guru" there) where it will be "easier" to troubleshoot...

Comment: Hi again chivracq, advise duly noted. I'll post this to iMacros Forum (Data-Extraction Sub-Forum) but do u mind i use some of your sentences above?

Comment: Well, start the Thread with the same Content/Info like you did here, with HTML Source, Script and Screenshot etc..., and and I'll post a Quote/Copy&Paste of the Answer I already posted here, + the "relevant" Comments, and we'll "start" from there... [Make sure to read the Forum Rules, I'm "stricter" with Quality on the iMacros Forum than "here", => will need to mention your FCI for example, + Screenshot needs to be uploaded to the Forum itself, etc...]

Comment: Good day chivracq, sorry for the delay in replying & posting in iMacros Forum. However, i've managed to extract most of required data by using Xpath. Thanks again for your guidance & support.